# (generalization) Maximum number of edges without a cycle of length k

Tags: graph-theory

I am baffled by the following solution to the problem from the *Proofs from the Book*. I was struggling with understanding the condition of not having a 4-cycle (C4) inside the graph. It seems to me to be a complete miracle that the absence of C4 is equivalent to the statement that **every pair of vertices has at most one common neighbor**. More precisely, the simplicity of the defining equation is very surprising to me and I would like to ask if this 'method' is generalizable.

Can one construct analogous inequalities for longer cycles in a similar fashion? Is it just luck that we can easily describe this short cycle globally?

.

[image]

(The maximum is found using this inequality, Cauchy-Schwartz, and the Handshaking lemma.)